# Tips and tricks regarding learning Xml

Tags: xml

I am noob in xml. I have started to learn it. While going through its tutorials on w3school, I noticed that all the time there are references to Java script and HTML. My first q is do i need to learn html and javascrpt aswell if I want to learn xml ? Secondly is it also necessary to learn things like XML XSLT, CSS, DTD as well ?

Comment: Not really but better learn HTML first. XML are just userdefined tags and namespace. Unless you want to lean advance xml like SOAP RSS basic HTML should get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the big picture [image: 1]
<sub>(source: [kensall.com](http://kensall.com/big-picture/bigpix22.gif))</sub>
.

Don't be affraid all the standards are used for their purposes.
To start with Xml I would recommend first to understand XML 1.0 for the syntax of the language. After this you need to understand how the structure is built, so take a look at the XML Schema documents.

After this, you can dive deeper in your interests, where you want to use XML.